# how can i get current cursor position with its line number in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need cursor's postion in textarea, if user hits the enter (return) it should give me the cursor location (line number in textarea) ? i want to validate 75 chars in textarea (15 chars in single row - total rows must be 5 user should not hit enter(return) after that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getCaret(el) {
  if (el.selectionStart) {
    return el.selectionStart;
  } else if (document.selection) {
    el.focus();

    var r = document.selection.createRange();
    if (r == null) {
      return 0;
    }

    var re = el.createTextRange(),
        rc = re.duplicate();
    re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
    rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re);

    return rc.text.length;
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would be much more helpful if it contained an additional explanation and if it used readable variable names instead of unclear abbreviations.